# Handle empty recordset in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

How can I handle the case when the following statement returns nothing, i.e. a non-existing record?

```
Form1.data1.RecordSource = "SELECT * " _
                         & "FROM Table " _
                         & "WHERE Column1 = " & txtSomeTextField.Text & ""
Form1.data1.Refresh
```

**Edit:** The error I get is:
    Run-time error '3021':
    No current record

Comment: What's the issue? - does it give you an error?

Comment: ON ERROR RESUME NEXT and then check err.Number.

No, there are no better error handling ways in VB, unfortunately.

don't forget ON ERROR GOTO 0 at the end.

Comment: @mihi - "there are no better error handling ways in VB" I am glad you are not on my dev team!

Answer (score 9):

Check for EOF And BOF of the record set ...

```
If Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF Then
   ' You have results
End If
```

Comment: If I do the check before the refresh then the recordset has not been refreshed.
If I do the check after the refresh then I can't catch the error.

Comment: Yes, do your query first, place the results into a new RecordSet object, check the RecordSet object and then set your Form property using your local variable.